# Connect my mobile phone as modem via bluetooth?

Tags: internet, bluetooth, internet-connection, modem, mobile-broadband

I can't find any way to do this in my Ubuntu 11.10. I can do this using data cable which Automatically connects me to Internet without headache.

My mobile model is Micromax Q-5fb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure to do this thing is fairly same for Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Here's how:

1. Click on Bluetooth icon on the panel, and *Set up New Device*
   [image: new device]
2. Switch on your mobile Bluetooth and make sure it's *visible*. Now select your mobile phone from Ubuntu options to pair it up with your Ubuntu. It might show some codes, just do what it says and go forward.
3. When finishing the setup, there will be a check box asking for whether you want to access Internet from your mobile using DUN connect. Selecting it will show you a window that looks like this:
   [image: mobile connection]
4. Now, in the next one, it asks you for your location, provider information. Select accordingly.
   [image: provider]
5. Make sure that you select your mobile Internet plan correctly. If you select something else other than your plan here, you may find that you ended up having a negative balance in your mobile phone in ten minutes - which obviously doesn't sound that good.
   [image: plan]

Keep going forward, and you should have your mobile Bluetooth connection setup and paired with Ubuntu. All you need to do next is to connect to that mobile network by clicking on network connections in the panel.

Also, disconnect from any other network (if you are connected), and make sure you don't put your mobile device half a kilometer away from your computer (for it to have good Bluetooth connection strength), to make things go smooth.

Good luck!